# mat-sidenav hiding content when initially opened

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Scenario :**

- I do have a mat-sidenav opening on the left and right. 
  Everything works fine when triggered by button click or any user interaction.
- But I also want to open this when page is loaded. And then I do have display issues. When the controlling variable `projectSelectorOpened` is set to true the side panel is hiding the page content.
  When triggered by user the content slides correctly to the middle.

Also tried to set the variable to true with setTimeout ... Works if set to some seconds. 
But this isn't what I want.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
<mat-sidenav #projectSelector mode="side" [(opened)]="projectSelectorOpened">
    <div class="list-group-item" (click)="projectSelectorOpened = !projectSelectorOpened">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> {{l10n.get('T_Projects')}}
    </div>
    <project-selector [selectedProjectId]="projectId" [selectedComponentId]="componentId"></project-selector>
</mat-sidenav>

<mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-content>

<mat-sidenav #projectSelector2 mode="side" position="end" [(opened)]="projectSelectorOpened">
    <div class="list-group-item" (click)="projectSelectorOpened = !projectSelectorOpened">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> {{l10n.get('T_Projects')}}
    </div>
    <project-selector [selectedProjectId]="projectId"></project-selector>
</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: Provide default value to `projectSelectorOpened` variable as true, its working fine. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-example-open-by-default?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html, if not good, then please create stackblitz demo reproducing this issue.

Comment: Found out, that this issue appears only in chrome browser

Comment: but the stackblitz demo i have provided is working on chrome browser.

Comment: It is interesting that i face the same issue, however, on resizing window it adjusts. I have container-fluid and some other component inside mat-sidenav-content, and somehow in your stackblitz it is not reproducible